# Fb_appid_access_token not set when redirect_uri present

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

When `redirect_uri` is provided in getLoginUrl for facebook login integration, the `fb_appid_access_token` session is not visible. For some reason the `fb_appid_access_token` session is not set or may be destroyed. But when i don't provide `redirect_uri`, the `fb_appid_access_token` is getting set and i am able to view it by using `print_r($_SESSION)`. Below is the code which i am using.

```
$loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email,publish_actions","redirect_uri"=>"absolute url"));
```

P.S Codeigniter framework and facebook-php-sdk are used

Comment: What exact value are you setting, and where exactly do you get redirected when you leave it out?

Comment: I am not setting any values. Facebook is setting some of the session variables in my domain and one of them is fb_appid_access_token.

Comment: You said you are providing a value for `redirect_uri`, and I want to know which one it is exactly.

Comment: In redirect_uri i am specifying `http://www.mywebsite.com` ie I am asking facebook to redirect to `http://www.mywebsite.com` if authentication is successful or failure. If one doesn't provide `redirect_uri`, then current browser url will be considered and redirected. More info on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/